Need help with Firealpaca brush script that draws different colours with the same luminance on each brush stroke
Soooo, I was attempting to make a brush, it has 2 functions, the first is to have a jitter effect, and the second is to have a random colour every time it makes a new brush stroke, but the random colour must have the same luminance/value as the foreground colour. I cant seem to figure the last part, it just makes a colour with different luminance each time I tried making brush strokes with it. Any help? (Firealpaca uses Lua, just a reminder)
Firstdraw = true
    
    function param1()
  -- minimum, maximum, default value
  return "random" , 0 , 100 , 2
end

function main(x, y, p)
    if Firstdraw then
        r, g, b = bs_fore()
        luminance = (r * 0.3) + (g * 0.59) + (b * 0.11)
        luminanceStart = luminance
        blue = math.random(0, luminance/0.11)
        luminance = luminance - blue*0.11
        red = math.random(0, luminance/0.3)
        luminance = luminance - red*0.3
        green = luminance/0.59
        luminanceEnd = (red * 0.3) + (green * 0.59) + (blue * 0.11)

        local sx = tostring(luminanceStart)
        local sv = tostring(luminanceEnd)
        local sy = tostring(red)
        local sp = tostring( green)
        local sd = tostring( blue)
        bs_debug_log( "sx: " .. sx .. " sv: " .. sv .. " sy: " .. sy .. " sp: " .. sp.. " sd: " .. sd )
        bs_debug_log("")

    end
    local width =  bs_width()
    local x, y = x+math.random(bs_param1()*-1, bs_param1())*p*width/10, y+math.random(bs_param1()*-1, bs_param1())*p*width/10
    local opacity = bs_opaque() * 255

    bs_ellipse(x, y, width, width, 0, red, green, blue, opacity)
    Firstdraw = false
    return 1
end


If you want to preserve luminance, maybe convert to HSL and then randomize. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793729/rgb-to-hsl-and-back-calculation-problems
